# SSH connection to virtual private cloud times out via proxy command but not via public host

Tags: ssh, amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc

I have a host in AWS with public DNS, bastion-prod, to which I can SSH from my local machine without any problems. From there, I can SSH to a host, reports-prod, in a virtual private cloud. However, when I try to SSH directly to reports-prod via a proxy command from my local machine, the request times out. I use the same key in both cases. Here is the verbose output of the SSH and my SSH config. What gives? Thanks for the help!

**SSH Config**

```
Host "bastion-prod"
  HostName <removed the actual public IP>
  User <removed the actual username>
  StrictHostKeyChecking no
  UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/Private_Key.pem

Host "reports-prod"
  HostName <removed the actual private IP>
  User <removed the actual username>
  StrictHostKeyChecking no
  UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/Private_Key.pem
  ProxyCommand ssh -W %h:%p bastion-prod
```

**Verbose SSH output**

```
$ ssh -vvv -F ~/.ssh/config_prod reports-prod
OpenSSH_6.2p2, OSSLShim 0.9.8r 8 Dec 2011
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/username/.ssh/config_prod
debug1: /Users/ibernshteyn/.ssh/config_prod line 155: Applying options for reports-prod
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Executing proxy command: exec ssh -W 10.0.11.51:22 bastion-prod
debug1: permanently_drop_suid: 503
debug3: Incorrect RSA1 identifier
debug3: Could not load "/Users/username/.ssh/Private_Key.pem" as a RSA1 public key
debug1: identity file /Users/username/.ssh/Private_Key.pem type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/username/.ssh/Private_Key.pem-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.2
ssh: connect to host 52.0.37.205 port 22: Operation timed out
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
```

**Edit 1**
To call it out, what's interesting are the last two lines

```
ssh: connect to host 52.0.37.205 port 22: Operation timed out
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
```

Why is there a timeout to 52.0.37.205 when I have no explicit attempt to connect to it? That is not the IP of either of the hosts. Although, bastion-prod IP does start with 52.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was some kind of problem reading the SSH config from the non-default SSH config file (config_prod). I put everything in the default 'config' file and dropped the -F flag and all is "well".